# How do I use a jQuery code for two or more options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use a jQuery code for two or more options?
My code :

```
   
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#select123' || '#select12').change(function() {
    jQuery('.content123' || '.content13').hide();
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
  }).trigger("change");
});
div.content123,div.content13 {
  display: none
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select123">
     <option value="content1" selected="selected">content1</option>
     <option value="content2">content2</option> 
    </select>

    <div id="content1" class="content123">
      text defult show
    </div>
    <div id="content2" class="content123">
     contentttttttt
    </div>

<select id="select12">
     <option value="content01" selected="selected">content1</option>
     <option value="content02">content2</option> 
    </select>

    <div id="content01" class="content13">
      text defult show
    </div>
    <div id="content02" class="content13">
     contentttttttt
    </div>
```

Comment: Reading the api docs would have let you answer this yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery('#select123, #select12')` will select both elements.

Multiple-Selector API

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: You want a `OR` for jQuery?

Comment: Each separate select run

Comment: In this case you need to create two blocks of code, one for each selector.

Comment: I want display sports table... 10 different table